Ошибка версии mysqlclient в django проекте
При выполнении миграции mysql базы данных в проекте на django появляется следующая ошибка:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\all\python_proj\flshop\django_project\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\all\python_proj\flshop\django_project\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\all\python_proj\blumhack\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\all\python_proj\blumhack\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\all\python_proj\blumhack\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 413, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "D:\all\python_proj\blumhack\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 459, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\all\python_proj\blumhack\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 107, in wrapper
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\all\python_proj\blumhack\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py", line 158, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "D:\all\python_proj\blumhack\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 313, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\all\python_proj\blumhack\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 89, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\all\python_proj\blumhack\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 63, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\all\python_proj\blumhack\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\all\python_proj\blumhack\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 316, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\all\python_proj\blumhack\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 292, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "D:\all\python_proj\blumhack\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\all\python_proj\blumhack\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 275, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "D:\all\python_proj\blumhack\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\all\python_proj\blumhack\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 258, in connect
    self.init_connection_state()
  File "D:\all\python_proj\blumhack\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 266, in init_connection_state
    super().init_connection_state()
  File "D:\all\python_proj\blumhack\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 225, in init_connection_state
    self.check_database_version_supported()
  File "D:\all\python_proj\blumhack\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 200, in check_database_version_supported
    raise NotSupportedError(
django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: MySQL 8.0.11 or later is required (found 5.7.37).

при установке mysqlclient устанавливается старая версия, которую не поддерживает django. Вопрос заключается в том, где найти ту самую версию 8.0.11?

Не mysqlclient, а MySQL, не надо их путать
